# Concept regarding coding with lots of GUI updates in Android (Gui Handlers)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, background-process, conceptual

I have the following pseudocode :

```
MySteps(){
  //Step A
  if (conditionA) {
    showwaitdialog(messageA); // shows wait dialog, so User knows app is running
    longrunnerA; // long running task, like downloading from internet.
    dismissdialog // closes the wait dialog.
  }
  //Step B
  if (conditionB && stepAfinished) { //real if not elseif
    showwaitdialog(messageB); // shows wait dialog
    longrunnerB; // long running task, like downloading from internet.
    dismissdialog
  }  
  //Step C
  if (conditionC && stepDfinished) { //real if not elseif
    showwaitdialog(messageC); // shows wait dialog
    longrunnerC; // long running task, like downloading from internet.
    dismissdialog
  }  
  if (!conditionA && !conditionB && !conditionC && allStepsfinished){
    startStepD();
  }
}
```

Now I like to implement this logic in my Android App:
With my knowledge I would code it as follow (also kind of pseodocode), which leads in very ugly code :

```
HandlerA(){
  dismissDialog();
  if(ConditionB){
    showwaitdialog(messageB); // shows wait dialog
    new BackgroundTask {
      longrunnerB; // long running task, like downloading from internet.
      callHandlerB();
    }
  }
}

HandlerB(){
  dismissDialog();
  if(ConditionC){
    showwaitdialog(messageC); // shows wait dialog
    new BackgroundTask {
      longrunnerC; // long running task, like downloading from internet.
      callHandlerC();
    }
  }
}

HandlerC(){
  dismissDialog();
  if(!ConditionA && !ConditionB && !ConditionC){
    new BackgroundTask {
      startStepD();
    }
  }
}


MySteps(){ // not correct name, because it calls only step A. I cant see,that there is a lot other stuff triggered. 
  showwaitdialog(messageA); // shows wait dialog
  new BackgroundTask(){
    longrunnerA(); // long running task, like downloading from internet.
    call HandlerA();
  }
}
```

This Code is distributed at different locations and the method "MySteps" has the wrong name, because it only does StepA.

How can I code this more compact and cleaner, so I will have a method MySteps(), which concentrates the entire logic and the GUI updates will be correct working ?

*** UPDATE ***

Coding with handlers is similar to coding with GOTO Statements. Every coder knows, we should avoid GOTO statements. Thats why I am looking for a better coding concept to implement the sample logic above.

Comment: What's meaning `longrunner` in Mysteps? (Method??)

Comment: This is a long running task. It doesn't matter what it does conceptional. Its just a task, that runs long. For example downloads data from internet.

Comment: okay, I think this logic seems to be handled using AsyncTask.

Comment: But with Asynctask we will get the same codestructure. The Question is not how to handle GUI updates. The question is how to write better code. It does not matter if you use Threads or Asynctask, right? Or if you think the code structur would change, can you show me a sample (psoedocode) ?

Comment: You probably should use only 1 Backound Task instead of 4. That would make things easier. I don't see a reason for 4 Tasks.

Comment: Its not solved for me to do it in one Background Task. I would be happy, if someone could help me in this situation.

Comment: OK sure, whats the problem? The dialog/UI stuff?

Comment: The problem is not technical. Its conceptional. Its working fine and its not new to me, because I have already implemented this with handlers since my app exists. The problem is, that if you want to write clean code, you would like to avoid using all these handlers. So I hoped, there would be a more elegant mechanism to concentrate the code at one place. You can compare the handlers as GOTO statements. Every coder knows that we should avoid GOTO Statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I think this pseudocode code can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

If your need funtion is similar to downloading a file, then this is probable a better choice.

**ExampleTask**

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private String message;

    public ExampleTask(Context context, String message)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dialog =new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.message = message;
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        showDialog();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            // implement download target url[i]
            if (isCancelled()) return false;
        }

        dismissDialog();
        return true;
    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        // show dialog
    }

    private void dismissDialog()
    {
        // dissmiss dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        //implements result handling
    }
}
```

**ExecuteTask**

```
new ExampleTask(this, "message").execute(url1, url2, url3);
```